# Get value in Create Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My model.

```
public class CustomUserTeam
{
    public bool IsCation { get; set; }
    public int SelectedPlayer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Player { get; set; }
}
```

My Create View

```
    @model List<superselector.Models.CustomUserTeam>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "UserPlayers", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Team</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Player
                </th>
                <th>
                    Caption
                </th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.SelectedPlayer, item.Player)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.SelectedPlayer)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => item.IsCation, true)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.IsCation)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

My Create Action

```
     [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(List<CustomUserTeam> utvm)// I get null here
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //db.tblUserTeams.Add(tbluserteam);
            //db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(utvm);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        //UserTeamViewModel utvm = new UserTeamViewModel();
        List<CustomUserTeam> UserTeam = new List<CustomUserTeam>();

        List<tblPlayer> batsmen = db.tblPlayers.Where(x => x.tblPlayerSpeciality.Id == 1 || x.tblPlayerSpeciality.Id == 3).OrderBy(x => x.PlayerName).ToList();
        List<tblPlayer> Bowlers = db.tblPlayers.Where(x => x.Speciality == 2 || x.Speciality == 3).OrderBy(x => x.PlayerName).ToList();
        List<tblPlayer> wk = db.tblPlayers.Where(x => x.Speciality == 4).OrderBy(x => x.PlayerName).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            UserTeam.Add(new CustomUserTeam() { Player = new SelectList(batsmen, "playerId", "PlayerName") });
        }

        UserTeam.Add(new CustomUserTeam() { Player = new SelectList(wk, "playerId", "PlayerName") });

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            UserTeam.Add(new CustomUserTeam() { Player = new SelectList(Bowlers, "playerId", "PlayerName") });
        }

        return View(UserTeam);
    }
```

The problem is when i click on "Create" on View, I get null in the Create Action's argument

I dont know whats wrong